# Need to identify SwingWorker completion to stop the current process?

Tags: java, swing

My aim is to select all the files named with MANI.txt which is present in their respective folders and then load path of the MANI.txt files different location in table. After I load the path in the table,I used to select needed path and modifiying those.

To load the MANI.txt files taking more time,because it may present more than 30 times in my workspace or etc. until load the files I want to give alarm to the user with help of ProgessBar.Once the list size has been populated I need to disable ProgressBar.

i came up with this ProgressBar, but progress bar operation gets complete or not, if the background process(finding files and putting their path in the table) got completed means, the result getting displayed and hiding the progress bar? i want the presence of progress bar opertion gets complete 100% in either case? please give me some ideas?how to implement it?

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.table.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;


 public class JTableHeaderCheckBox extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
protected int counter = 0;
Object colNames[] = { "", "Path" };
Object[][] data = {};
DefaultTableModel dtm;
JTable table;
JButton but;
java.util.List list;
File folder;
JProgressBar current;
JFrame fr1, frame;
int num = 0;
JProgressBar pbar;
JTableHeaderCheckBox it;


   public void buildGUI() throws InterruptedException {
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);
    table = new JTable(dtm);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    int vColIndex = 0;
    TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
    int width = 10;
    col.setPreferredWidth(width);
    int vColIndex1 = 1;
    TableColumn col1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex1);
    int width1 = 500;
    col1.setPreferredWidth(width1);
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    // chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose workSpace Path");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                                                                        {
                }
    String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    folder = new File(path);
    but = new JButton("REMOVE");

    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

        @Override
        public Object doInBackground() {
            GatheringFiles ob = new GatheringFiles();
            list = ob.returnlist(folder);

            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // java.util.List list = (java.util.List)get();

            for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
                dtm.addRow(new Object[] { new Boolean(false),
                        list.get(x).toString() });
            }
            try {
                JPanel pan = new JPanel();
                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
                TableColumn tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                tc.setCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
                tc.setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
                tc.setHeaderRenderer(new CheckBoxHeader(
                        new MyItemListener()));

                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                pan.add(sp);
                pan.add(but);
                f.add(pan);
                f.setSize(700, 100);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);

                if (list.size() >= 0) {
                    // hide the progress bar
                    frame.hide();

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }


        }
    };

    worker.execute();
    but.addActionListener(this);
    //calling progressbar
    if(!path.isEmpty())
    {
    SwingProgressBar();
    }

}

public void SwingProgressBar() {
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.black);
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.white);
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", new Color(8, 32, 128));

    pbar = new JProgressBar();
    pbar.setMinimum(0);
    pbar.setMaximum(100);
    pbar.setForeground(Color.RED);
    pbar.setStringPainted(true);

    it = new JTableHeaderCheckBox();
    frame = new JFrame("Loading");
    final JLabel lb = new JLabel("0");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // frame.setContentPane(it);

    frame.add(pbar);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    counter = 0;
    Thread runner = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            counter = 0;
            while (counter <= 99) {
                Runnable runme = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pbar.setValue(counter);
                    }
                };
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runme);
                counter++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    runner.start();

}

public void updateBar(int newValue) {
    pbar.setValue(newValue);
}

class MyItemListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof AbstractButton == false)
            return;
        boolean checked = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
        for (int x = 0, y = table.getRowCount(); x < y; x++) {
            table.setValueAt(new Boolean(checked), x, 0);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new JTableHeaderCheckBox().buildGUI();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    });
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getSource() == but) {
        System.err.println("table.getRowCount()" + table.getRowCount());
        for (int x = 0, y = table.getRowCount(); x < y; x++) {
            if ("true".equals(table.getValueAt(x, 0).toString())) {
                System.err.println(table.getValueAt(x, 0));
                System.err.println(list.get(x).toString());
                delete(list.get(x).toString());
            }

        }
    }

}

public void delete(String a) {

    String delete = "C:";

    System.err.println(a);
    try {
        File inFile = new File(a);

        if (!inFile.isFile()) {
                            return;
        }

        // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the             // filename.
        File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;

        // Read from the original file and write to the new
        // unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.err.println(line);
            line = line.replace(delete, " ");
            pw.println(line);
            pw.flush();

        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        // Delete the original file
        if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
        }

        // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   }


   class CheckBoxHeader extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer,
    MouseListener {
protected CheckBoxHeader rendererComponent;
protected int column;
protected boolean mousePressed = false;

public CheckBoxHeader(ItemListener itemListener) {
    rendererComponent = this;
    rendererComponent.addItemListener(itemListener);
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (table != null) {
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        if (header != null) {
            rendererComponent.setForeground(header.getForeground());
            rendererComponent.setBackground(header.getBackground());
            rendererComponent.setFont(header.getFont());
            header.addMouseListener(rendererComponent);
        }
    }
    setColumn(column);
    rendererComponent.setText("Check All");
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    return rendererComponent;
}

protected void setColumn(int column) {
    this.column = column;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}

protected void handleClickEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    if (mousePressed) {
        mousePressed = false;
        JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) (e.getSource());
        JTable tableView = header.getTable();
        TableColumnModel columnModel = tableView.getColumnModel();
        int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
        int column = tableView.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);

        if (viewColumn == this.column && e.getClickCount() == 1
                && column != -1) {
            doClick();
        }
    }
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    handleClickEvent(e);
    ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).repaint();
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    mousePressed = true;
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
  }

 //

   import java.io.File; 
   import java.util.*; 
   public class GatheringFiles { 
   public static List returnlist(File folder) 
   { 
       List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>(); 
       List<File> list1 = new ArrayList<File>(); 
       getFiles(folder, list); 
       return list;
   } 
   private static void getFiles(File folder, List<File> list) { 
   folder.setReadOnly(); 
   File[] files = folder.listFiles(); 
   for(int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {

if( "MANI.txt".equals(files[j].getName()))
{

    list.add(files[j]); 
}


  if(files[j].isDirectory()) 

  getFiles(files[j], list); 
  } 
  } 
   }
```